# iOS preload notification items in the app, why not?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Imagine that you have Gmail app installed on your iPhone and you are in the area with bad/unstable 2G internet connection, you take your phone and you see a notification about new mail from Gmail app, you see the subject and even few words from the letter itself, but when you swipe the notification to view the whole letter you can't do it because at that moment your 2G connection is already lost. Pretty annoying actually.

So the question is: why apps do not somehow preload pieces of information that they've already shown to the user as notification? In that case, why Gmail doesn't preload the letter, which I've notified about? Is it iOS issue or apps just don't do that?

Comment: Battery life, network usage, capability. A range of reasons really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's not the design of a push notification. You can only send 256KB  data using it. When you swipe to view the notification - a network call is then made to receive the rest of the notification. This saves battery life and even network costs. Imaging if a push notification downloads all the data for each notification.. that would go through your battery life quick, while you're not even using the phone.

Comment: Ok, what about preloading 256 KB in the app? Does Gmail retrieve only few words each time or 256 KB of the letter? Because if the latter, then I suppose it could use this data to preload letters, which are less than 256 KB.

Comment: You need to understand that a push notification doesn't only contain your data (Text in this case) it also contains other info, like device token and formatting etc - the whole size of the notification cannot grow bigger than 256KB. So, hence why only a few strings of text are sent and some other data your app can use to take the user to the correct screen when the app launches.

Answer (score 0):

Man there is limit of data in Push Notification is 256KB.
So more data can not be send in push Notification.